# simple password protect your android application

Tags: android, passwords, protected

i am new to android development.
i want to create a simple password protected application which asks for a password on launch. the login dialog should ask only for a password or exit. thats it! if password is entered correctly then application should launch or else the user should be asked to enter password again and an exit option should be given.

Answers from with all the details from scratch are most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps :

1. Make a separate Activity, in its onCreate , pop up an Alert Dialogue.
2. If the password is correct, then only start your activity using Intent.
3. else finish() the current activity.
4. You can save your password either in a database or inside SharedPreferences.
5. refer internet to use database or SharedPreferences.

eg of SharedPreferences:

```
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
        SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;
            mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("usernamepassworddetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
        myEditor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
        myEditor.commit();

//In this code you can add the details


myEditor.putInt("username", imageWidth);
       myEditor.putInt("password", imageHeight);
       myEditor.putInt("position", currentPosition);
       myEditor.commit();
```

//code to retrive data

```
mySharedPreferences.getInt("username", 0)
mySharedPreferences.getInt("password", 0)
```

For database related code, refer to this link:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Let me know if this of any help.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually came in via Google looking for a way to password protect a certain activity and your answer pointed me in the right direction.